# Python web scraping on tables with customizable dropdowns

Tags: python, html

I am a novice who is trying to put together my first webpage scraping function, and running into some HTTP problems that I don't fully understand. For reference, I am trying to scrape from [FanGraphs ZIPS projection page](https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&type=zips&team=0&lg=al&players=0).

Their page defaults to displaying a table with 30 players, but you can edit the webpage such that the table displays 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 500 or 1000 results per page. Ideally I would select the option for 500 results per page, but when I change the dropdown menu, the URL remains unchanged, so I'm trying write a script to get the HTML code and edit the attributes of the HTML page before trying to request that variation of the webpage. (If you view the page source, it's on line 1247)

Alternatively, you can cycle through additional pages with arrow button hyperlinks on the page, but they do not change the URL either.

I got around this problem for positional players since I can scrape each position separately and then concatenate the separate Pandas data frames, but I'm pretty oblivious about how HTTP requests work and was hoping for some help / guidance.

I tried something like:

```py
from requests import Request, Session
url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=pit&type=zips&team=0&lg=al&players=0'
page = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
resultSet = soup.findAll(value=30)
for result in resultSet:
    result["value"]="500"
s = Session()
req = requests.Request('POST', url, data = {'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Input value': 500})
resp = s.send(prepped)
print(resp.status_code)
```

My thought was to scrape the structure, edit the configuration to match my desired webpage, and then regurgitate the fixed structure to scrape the data. Then I realized that I had no idea what I was doing.

A few things:
Am I "not even wrong" here?  Is this possible with requests or would I need something like Selenium? Am I improperly using POST?

Side note: If context helps, for positional players I did this (would be doing the same thing for pitchers):

```
base_url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=&stats=bat&type=zips&team=0&lg=all&players=0'
positions = ['c', '1b', '2b', '3b', 'ss', 'lf', 'cf', 'rf']

def generate_positional_urls(urlRoot=base_url, pos=positions):
    index = base_url.index('pos=') + 4 position after
    urlList = []
    numPositions = len(positions)
    for i in range(numPositions):
        position = pos[i]
        tempURL = urlRoot[:index] + position + urlRoot[index:]
        urlList.append(tempURL)

    return urlList
```

Which feeds into this:

```py
def generate_df(url):
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

masterTable = soup.findAll('table', {"class": "rgMasterTable"}, {"id": "ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ct100"})
table_rows = masterTable[0].find_all('tr')

data = []

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    data.append(row)
    
headers = masterTable[0].find_all("thead")
colElements = headers[0].find_all("tr")

soupColResults = colElements[1].findChildren("a")
colStrings = [element.text for element in soupColResults]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = colStrings

df.drop(columns=[''], inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[3:, :]

return df
```

Then it's easy enough to loop through and concatenate data frames, but for this HTTP problem, I really don't know what I am doing.

Note: I am doing this to try to learn and practice Python. I can easily avoid this by using my web browser to click on the hyperlink to export the data to a csv, so don't exert too much effort figuring out unnecessary tedium.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to scrape an `html` table into a `pandas` dataframe. This can be done without `BeautifulSoup` using [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).
Second, always keep track of what is happening in the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) of Chrome or Firefox. You can see what gets loaded when you click to change the number of results. You can copy the request [as `curl`](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas) and then convert this to a python `request`, for example using [this tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/). You can now load the data and pass them to `pandas` directly. Note that I had to remove `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` for readability, but you can get them from the page source code or from the `curl` command as indicated above.

```
import requests

params = (
    ('pos', 'all'),
    ('stats', 'pit'),
    ('type', 'zips'),
    ('team', '0'),
    ('lg', 'al'),
    ('players', '0'),
)

data = {
  'RadScriptManager1_TSM': '',
  '__EVENTTARGET': 'ProjectionBoard1$dg1',
  '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'FireCommand:ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00;PageSize;1000',
  '__VIEWSTATE': '', #text removed for readability
  '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'C239D6F0',
  '__SCROLLPOSITIONX': '0',
  '__SCROLLPOSITIONY': '0',
  '__EVENTVALIDATION': '', #text removed for readability
  'ProjectionBoard1_tsStats_ClientState': '{"selectedIndexes":["1"],"logEntries":[],"scrollState":{}}',
  'ProjectionBoard1_tsPosition_ClientState': '{"selectedIndexes":["0"],"logEntries":[],"scrollState":{}}',
  'ProjectionBoard1$rcbTeam': 'All Teams',
  'ProjectionBoard1_rcbTeam_ClientState': '',
  'ProjectionBoard1$rcbLeague': 'AL',
  'ProjectionBoard1_rcbLeague_ClientState': '',
  'ProjectionBoard1_tsProj_ClientState': '{"selectedIndexes":["0"],"logEntries":[],"scrollState":{}}',
  'ProjectionBoard1_tsUpdate_ClientState': '{"selectedIndexes":[],"logEntries":[],"scrollState":{}}',
  'ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$PageSizeComboBox': '1000',
  'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState': '{"logEntries":[],"value":"1000","text":"1000","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}',
  'ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox': '30',
  'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState': '',
  'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ClientState': ''
}

response = requests.post('https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx', params=params, data=data)
df = pd.read_html(response.text)
```

`read_html` returns a list of all tables as dataframes, the table you want can be accessed as `df[8]`. Output `df[8].head()`:

|  | Name | Unnamed: 1 | Team | W | L | ERA | GS | G | IP | H | ER | HR | SO | BB | WHIP | K/9 | BB/9 | FIP | WAR | ADP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Lucas Giolito | nan | CHW | 16 | 7 | 3 | 30 | 30 | 180 | 129 | 60 | 21 | 248 | 56 | 1.03 | 12.4 | 2.8 | 2.98 | 5.8 | 18.3 |
| 1 | Gerrit Cole | nan | NYY | 16 | 8 | 3.21 | 32 | 32 | 193.3 | 155 | 69 | 27 | 260 | 49 | 1.06 | 12.1 | 2.28 | 3.18 | 5.7 | 7.4 |
| 2 | Shane Bieber | nan | CLE | 14 | 9 | 3.51 | 32 | 32 | 197.7 | 177 | 77 | 26 | 230 | 36 | 1.08 | 10.47 | 1.64 | 3.23 | 5.4 | 10 |
| 3 | Jose Berrios | nan | MIN | 13 | 10 | 3.89 | 31 | 31 | 180.3 | 167 | 78 | 24 | 187 | 56 | 1.24 | 9.33 | 2.79 | 3.98 | 3.5 | 82.9 |
| 4 | Chris Sale | nan | BOS | 9 | 5 | 3.35 | 20 | 20 | 121 | 103 | 45 | 14 | 147 | 28 | 1.08 | 10.93 | 2.08 | 3.23 | 3.4 | 297 |

Comment: Thanks for this, I was completely unaware of pd.read_html, copying curl requests, and everything above... I kept going down rabbit holes that led me into several different packages (urllib, request, selenium) each of which I understood less than the prior package and just conceded I was trying to force my way to a solution blindly throwing darts...