# Python - How to use scrape table from website with dropdown of available rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the earnings calendar data from the table from zacks.com and the url is attached below.

https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/aapl/earnings-calendar

The thing is I am trying to scrape all data from the table, but it has a dropdown list to select 10, 25, 50 and 100 rows on a page. Ideally I want to scrape for all 100 rows but when I select 100 from the dropdown list, the url doesn't change. My code is below.

To note that the website blocks user-agent so I had to use chrome driver to impersonate human visiting the web. The obtained result from the pd.read_html is a list of all the tables and the d[4] returns the earnings calendar with only 10 rows (which I want to change to 100)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('../files/chromedriver96')
symbol = 'AAPL'
url = 'https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/{}/earnings-calendar'.format(symbol)
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
d = pd.read_html(content)
d[4]
```

So calling help for anyone to guide me on this

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: it looks like my last post was downgraded due to lack of clear articulation and evidence of showing the past research. Maybe I am still a newbie to posting questions on this site. Actually, I have found several pages including this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576711/python-web-scraping-on-tables-with-customizable-dropdowns) with the same issue but the solutions didn't seem to work for me, which is why I came to post this as a new question

---

UPDATE 12/05:
Thanks a lot for the advise. As commented below, I finally got it working. Below is the code I used

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#earnings_announcements_earnings_table_length')
time.sleep(1)
hundreds = dropdown.find_element_by_xpath(".//option[. = '100']")
hundreds.click()
```

Comment: One way to see what might be going on is in your browser's dev console, look to see what requests that page makes when you change from 10 to 100 on the drop down. When I look at this it seems that the page doesn't make any new requests. To me this indicates that the 100 rows are already stored in the javascript and just displayed when the user changes the display option.

Comment: Yep true. I did the same but saw the same as you had seen, i.e. no new requests. Any idea on how to take out the data from the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Having taken a look this is not going to be something that is easy to scrape. Given that the table is produced from the javascript I would say you have two options.

**Option one:**

Use selenium to render the page allowing the javascript to run. This way you can simply use the id/class of the drop down to interact with it.
You can then scrape the data by looking at the values in the table.

**Option two:**

This is the more challenging one. Look through the data that the page gets in response and try to find requests which result in the data you then see on the page. By cross-referencing these there will be a way to directly request the data you want.
You may find that to get at the data you want you need to accept a key from the original request to the page and then send that key as part of a second request. This way should allow you to scrape the data without having to run a selenium instance which will run more efficiently.

My personal suggestion is to go with option one as computer resources are cheap and developer time expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried with option #1 and actually I had studied a bit with javascript. It is finally working now. What I did was I used Selenium to impersonate a mouse to click on the "show" 100 option, and then scrape the data table.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this same problem, and I was having trouble getting the hundreds.click() part of the code to work with Firefox.  So I looked into the page and found that the data is actually stored in an object called "document.obj_data".  So when you change the webpage selector, it just runs a script that accesses that data which is already loaded in your browser.  So you can access this data directly instead of manipulating the browser to display the table correctly and then data from the table.  It does have some HTML code inside the datatable, so you'd need to parse that, but this does offer a way to get to the data directly instead of manipulating the page which can be tricky with selenium.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import selenium as se
from selenium import webdriver

import re
import ast


os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
options = se.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
browser = se.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

symbol = 'AAPL'
url = 'https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/{}/earnings-calendar'.format(symbol)

browser.get(url)

content = browser.page_source

"document.obj_data"
compiled = re.compile('"earnings_announcements_earnings_table"\s+\:', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
match = re.search(compiled, content)
if match:
    source = content[match.end(): len(content)]

compiled = re.compile('"earnings_announcements_sales_table"', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
match = re.search(compiled, source)
if match:
    source = source[0: match.start()]

result = ast.literal_eval(str(source).strip('\r\n\t, '))

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
           0        1      2      3                                                                     4                                                                      5            6
0     5/4/23   3/2023  $1.44  $1.52    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+0.08</div>    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+5.56%</div>  After Close
1     2/2/23  12/2022  $1.93  $1.88  <div class="right neg negative neg_icon showinline down">-0.05</div>  <div class="right neg negative neg_icon showinline down">-2.59%</div>  After Close
2   10/27/22   9/2022  $1.26  $1.29    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+0.03</div>    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+2.38%</div>  After Close
3    7/28/22   6/2022  $1.14  $1.20    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+0.06</div>    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+5.26%</div>  After Close
4    4/28/22   3/2022  $1.43  $1.52    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+0.09</div>    <div class="right pos positive pos_icon showinline up">+6.29%</div>  After Close
```